# PHP - How can i do an array for each table?

Tags: php, arrays

i know that this is a really noob question, but i'm learning how to use arrays now, and i want to know how can i put two tables in different arrays, and combine both.

I'm building an menu, and this menu got submenus, i created two tables, one for the menu, and another one for the submenu, and i want to combine both, i will do something like this:

```
<ul>
<li>Menu</li>
<ul>
<li>Submenu</li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

So, i have my function and query here

```
function addjo(){
global $name, $ii, $array;


    addjoview($name, $ii, $array);
}

    $query= ("select * from menu inner join submenu on menu.menu_id=submenu.menu_id");
    $array = db_array($query, 'a+');
    $ii   = count($array);
```

And i'm calling this function here

```
 <?php
 function  addjoview($name, $ii, $array){

               for ($i = 0; $i < $ii; $i++) {
               $id = $array[$i]['menu_id'];
               $submenu_url  = $array[$i]['submenu_url'];
               $menu_id  = $array[$i]['menu_id'];


            echo $menu_id;

            echo '<br>';
               }



         }
           ?>
```

Comment: good you are using the JOIN now, but what is the problem with this code?

Comment: Everything is inside the loop, thats why i want to create and different array for each table, the menu table only have 4 columns and the script is reading everything 10 times, because the submenu have 10 columns. Resuming, i want to separate the menu and the submenu in different loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing what you really need to do is read your menu/submenu data into a two-dimensional array.  In order to do this, let's begin with your query.  Currently you are not doing your don't do any ordering on your select statement.  You also have not shared your tables structure, so I will assume that you have something like this:

menu table:

```
menu_id
menu_label
menu_order
```

submenu table

```
submenu_id
menu_id
submenu_label
submenu_url
submenu_order
```

Now, let's write a useful query:

```
SELECT
    m.menu_label AS menu_label,
    s.submenu_label AS submenu_label,
    s.submenu_url AS submenu_url
FROM menu AS m
INNER JOIN submenu AS s
    ON m.menu_id = s.menu_id
ORDER BY m.menu_order ASC, s.submenu_order ASC
```

Now let's see how to work with this data:

```
$menu_array = array();
while ($row = /* your DB row fetch here */) {
    $array[$row['menu_label']][] = array(
       'label' => $row['submenu_label'],
       'url' => $row['submenu_url']
    );
}
```

Now your array may look like this:

```
Array(
    'Menu Label #1' => array(
        0 => array(
            'label' => 'Menu #1, Submenu #1 label',
            'url' => 'http://menu1.submenu1.url'
        ),
        ... /* next item under Menu #1 */
    ),
    'Menu Label #2' => array(
        ...
    ),
    ...
)
```

You then output the array using nested loops:

```
foreach ($menu_array as $menu_label => $submenu_array) {
    echo '<ul><li>' . $menu_label . '</li><ul>';
    foreach ($submenu_array as $submenu_item) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . $submenu_item['url'] . '">' . $submenu_item['label'] . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul></ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is single array:

```
SELECT menu.id, menu.name, submenu.id, submenu.name
FROM menu
LEFT JOIN submenu on menu.menu_id=submenu.menu_id
```

Then

```
$menu = array();
while(list($mid, $mname, $sid, $sname) = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     if (!isset($menu[$mid])) {
          $menu[$mid] = array('name' => $mname, 'sub' => array());
     }
     $menu[$mid]['sub'][$sid] = array('name' => $sname);
}
```

This'd give you something like:

```
Array (
   1 => array(
        'name' => 'parent menu item #1',
        'sub' => array(
           1 => 'first submenu',
           2 => 'second submenu'
           ...
        )),
   2 => array(
        'name' => ' parent second item',
        'sub' => array(
            1 => 'item in submenu #2'
     etc...
```